# Handling page transitions in React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When transitioning between pages, it doesn't cause a re-render, as such componentDidMount isn't called each time. I have a translation element that I want to run every time the user goes to that page. I can't use ComponentWillUpdate because there's a textInput that causes the animation to reset each time the user types anything.

Comment: Are we talking about a single page app? If it doesn't rerender, it's because you aren't changing the props?  Why does the translation element have to run every time? Can you use `useEffect()` ?

Comment: This is multipage using react native navigation to navigate between pages. Its basically transitioning a bottom drawer up when you navigate to the next page to make the transition smoother. Is there a way to capture the page transition in useEffect()?

Comment: [`react-native-navigation`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), right?

Comment: sorry rather react-navigation: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation

Comment: I found a solution:
 use should component update and check for the page value, then use componentDidUpdate to call the animation.